# How to view all new resource provisions in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud

I am trying create a automation based on the new resource provisions in AWS. but i can't find any service/api which helps to view new provisions. I have tried to use CloudTrail to check create APIs. but CloudTrail logs are not enough for my use case.

Is there any service/api for this use case?

Comment: New would be relative to what?

Comment: like anything created in aws account, it can be ec2, s3 bucket, ebs anything.

Comment: There is no such functionality. The closest would be probably to scan CloudTrial for api events related to creation of resources. But there are hundreds or more of them.

Comment: you guys are correct. at the end, I decided to use cloud trail, I can't find anything else. the issue with cloud trail is, event structure is different for different events. so i need to write separate parsers for collecting resource id of the provisioned product.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AWS Config or AWS CloudTrail services for this, but, for AWS Config you will need to specify which kind of resource you want to be notified, like the following:

```
{
    "source": [
        "aws.config"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "Config Configuration Item Change"
    ],
    "detail": {
    "messageType": [
        "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"
    ],
    "configurationItem": {
        "resourceType": [
            "AWS::EC2::Instance"
        ],
        "configurationItemStatus": [
            "ResourceDiscovered"
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

For more information of how to do this with AWS Config, check this link: [Receive custom email notifications when a resource is created with AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-email-resource-created/)

If you want something to check the changes on Console, or other kind of changes you will need to use AWS CloudTrail, together with the AWS Lambda service.

An example can be found here: [Get Real-time Alerts When Users Modify AWS Infrastructure](https://towardsdatascience.com/protect-your-infrastructure-with-real-time-notifications-of-aws-console-user-changes-3144fd18c680)

In both you will need a service like AWS SNS to send the notifications.